# Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main"

Tags: fastapi, huggingface-transformers, onnxruntime

I am unable to run the program due to an error: "Error loading the ASGI app. Could not import module 'main'." What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

I encountered an error when running the command "uvicorn main:app". I want to display Swagger UI.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow! From just an error message, it will be completely impossible for anyone to help you. You need to include enough code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What's your python file name? The first part before `:` should be the name of your module - in this case, probably the python file name, while the part after `:` should be the variable name inside your file. You'll have to provide more information for anyone to say anything useful.